# Is there any way, how to get the redirect uri?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, webassembly, http-redirect

**Background:**

- Let's have a WebAssembly (wasm) originating from `.net` code.
- This wasm uses `HttpClient` and `HttpClientHandler` to access a backend API at `https://api.uri`.
- The actual backend API location might change in time (like `https://api.uri/version-5`), but there is still this fixed endpoint, which provides redirection (`3xx` response) to the current location (which is in the same domain).
- The API allows CORS, meaning it sends e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` headers in the responses.

**In the normal (non-wasm) world, one just:**

- Plainly `GET`s the `https://api.uri` with no additional headers (CORS safe).
- Retrieve the `Location:` header (containing e.g. `https://api.uri/version-5`) from the `3xx` response as the final URI.
- `GET`s/`POST`s the final URI with additional headers (as needed, e.g. custom, auth, etc.).

*Note: In ideal world, the redirection is handled transparently and the first two steps can just be omitted.*

**Although in the wasm world:**

- You are not allowed to (let the wasm/browser) send the `OPTIONS` pre-flight requests to a redirecting endpoint (`https://api.uri`).
- You can't send any non-cors headers, when wanting to prevent pre-flight requests (reason for two stages, plain and full, described above).
- You can't see the `Location:` header value (like `https://api.uri/version-5`) when trying the manual redirection (`HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false`), because the response is just artificially crafted with HTTP status code of `0` and `ReasonPhrase == "opaqueredirect"` - adoption to browser's Fetch API. **What a nonsense! #1...**
- You can't see the auto-followed `Location:` header value in `response.RequestMessage?.RequestUri`, when trying the (default) automatic redirection (`HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true`), because there is still the original URI (`https://api.uri`) instead of the very expected auto-followed one (`https://api.uri/version-5`). **What a nonsense! #2...**
- You can't send the full blown request with all the headers and rely on the automatic redirection, because it would trigger pre-flight, which is sill not allowed on redirecting endpoint.

So, the obvious question is:

**Is there ANY way, how to handle such simple scenario from the Web Assembly?**
(and not crash on CORS)

```
GET https://api.uri => 3xx, Location: https://api.uri/version-5
GET https://api.uri/version-5, Authorization: Basic BlaBlaBase64= ; Custom: Cool-Value => 200
```

*Note: All this has been discovered within the Uno Platform wasm head, but I believe it applies for any .net wasm.*

*Note: I also guess "disabled" CORS (on the request side, via `Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors`) wouldn't help either, as then such request is not allowed to have additional headers/methods, right?*